# Meteor: what can I use instead of setTimeout to reactive DOM changes?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I use materialbox (jQuery plugin to display Material Design lightbox style) when a new photo was taken from mobile end added to a dynamic list.
When photo is ready and visible in the DOM, a template event starts:

```js
Template.item.events({
'click .materialboxed':function(e,t){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.materialboxed').materialbox();
        },0)
    }
});
```

the DOM:

```html
<div class="col s2" style="text-align:left;">
  {{#if pictureExist}}
  <img src="{{picture}}" alt="" class="responsive-img materialboxed"> <!-- notice the "circle" class -->
  {{else}}
  <div class="takePicture"><i class="mdi-image-photo-camera small"></i></div>
  {{/if}}
</div>
```

Is there a best Meteor way instead setTimeout to instantiate jQuery code in reactive data?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the timer.

```
Template.item.events({
    'click .materialboxed':function(e,t){
                $('.materialboxed').materialbox();
        }
    });
```

It should work.

Comment: Thanks @Ethaan, but I need to start materialboxed within an Event, when I click in to the picture.

Comment: @Arcy check answer update, maybe something like that? using Session to know the event is triggered and use it on a rendered function?

Comment: don't works for new picture, but only for existing ones... :-(

Comment: Check new answer update, maybe is for the Session, when she initialize the materialBoxed, we return the Session to false.

Comment: Now works exactly ad before, but I need to do two clicks to open the picture just created. The others one just one click..

Comment: hmm use 2 diferrents events?

Comment: @Arcy did you try the other solution?

Comment: Hi @Ethaan, it works fine without timer and without rendered initialization because I don't iterate pictures within {{#each}}. Two clicks problem is related to jQuery plugin. Update your answer removing rendered and autorun ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have is perfectly fine in the Meteor world.

Since you do not want to instantiate anything when the Template is created, and you are not looking to track the state of the Template, then registering an event to call that bit of jQuery code seems like the straightforward way of going about it.

EDIT: Looked at your response to another answer, here is what you need:

```
Template.item.rendered = function () {

  # this.$() will only look for elements inside this template
  this.$('.materialboxed').materialbox();
};
```

To optimize your implementation a bit, we only initiate your jQuery plugin on the element that is clicked on.  Instead of initializing it onto every element with a `.materialboxed` class each time an `item` template is rendered.

The `template.$()` function works exactly like jQuery but only finds elements within the template.  I am not sure how this function works with jQuery plugins, but you could first return the exact element using this function, save it, and then convert it to a jQuery object manually.

More info on this here:
http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Blaze-TemplateInstance-findAll

Comment: Thank you @Sam, but also with adding THIS, new pictures required two clicks to open correctly...but old picture works fine with one click. There are still reactive rendering problem.. :-( for more clarity: the first time I click in the new picture I need to clicks, the second time just one...

Comment: Ah I thought you were iterating over each picture where each picture is an `item` template.  In this case you should just put the `$('.materialboxed').materialbox();` call at the very end of whatever function you have that inserts a picture or just keep doing it with the setTimeout if that is working.